# R convert time to time of day

Tags: r

Is there a function or an elegant way to convert time to a user friendly time of day string?

For example, if it is 9am right now, then

```
> time_of_day(Sys.time())
[1] "morning"
```

If it was 3pm, it would return

```
> time_of_day(Sys.time())
[1] "afternoon"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware if such a function exists but it would not be difficult to write one of your own. Here's a way based on hour of the day.

```
time_of_day <- function(time) {

   hr <- lubridate::hour(time)
   dplyr::case_when(hr > 6 & hr < 12 ~ 'morning', 
                    hr >= 12 & hr < 16 ~ 'afternoon', 
                    hr >= 16 & hr <= 20 ~ 'evening', 
                    TRUE ~ 'night')
}

time_of_day(Sys.time())
#[1] "morning"
```

Answer (score 4):

Ronak beat me to it, but here's an option using lubridate and an ifelse statement:

```
time_day <- function(current_time) {
ifelse(am(current_time) == 'TRUE',
   'morning',
   'afternoon')
}


time_day(Sys.time())
```